# Combining two dataframes with pandas/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to write script that gets the data from two different databases and gives the result which is a CSV file with combined data.

I managed to get data using psycopg2 and pandas read_sql_query, I turned results into two different dataframes and all of that works great. I wrote all of that with only a little information about those databases so I used databases I had and some simple queries.
All of that is on my github:

https://github.com/tomasz-urban/sql-db-get

With more detailed info about what needs to be done I'm stuck...

In the first database there are users limitations: lim_val_1 and lim_val_2 together with user_id (couple thousand rows). Second one holds usage with val_1 and val_2 gathered every some period of time (couple hundred thousand rows).

I need to get those rows where users reach their limits (doesn't matter if it is lim_val_1 or lim_val_2 or both, I need all of that).

To visualize it better there are some simple tables in the link:
[Databases info with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qmmb.png)

My last approach:

```
result_query = df2.loc[(df2['val_1'] == df1['lim_val_1']) & (df2['val_2'] == df1['lim_val_2'])]
output_data = pd.DataFrame(result_query)
```

and I'm getting an error:
"ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

I cannot label those columns the same so I think this solution will not work for me. I also tried merging  with no result.
Anyone could help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since df1 and df2 have different numbers of rows, you cannot compare the values directly, try joining the data frames and then select where the conditions are met.

If `user_id` is the index of both df:

```
df_3 = df1.join(df2)
df_3[
    (df_3['val_1'] == df_3['lim_val_1']) |
    (df_3['val_2'] == df_3['lim_val_2']
]
```

You might want to replace `==` in for `>=` in case where limits can be surpassed.

Comment: The `.join` didn't work, I was getting the error: "ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified". I tried with suffixes but I was getting some weird outputs. But I tried Your code with `.merge` and it worked great! I tried `.merge` before but my approach had to be wrong: `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['user_id', 'val_1', 'val_2']], on=['user_id'])` because I was getting some errors. Thank You very much for Your help!